# How to convert a time from text to time format in postgresQL?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have done this query in PostgreSQL:

```
select b.movement_category, 
round(count(*)*100/case when count(*) = 0 then 1 else sum(count(*)) over () end::numeric,2) cnt_pct
from ( 
select distinct a.imei_number, a.movement_category
from dataview a
where a.data_capture_time between '2018-07-28' and '2018-07-28'
and a.movement_category <> ''
and fn_distance_km(23.728264,90.411367,cast(a.latitude as double precision),cast(a.longitude as double precision))<=20
) b                
group by b.movement_category
```

Comment: got some examples of what you want? postgres understands most common text formats.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I've removed your unrelated question. Please research that thoroughly before asking a clear and detailed question in a separate post.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html) for formatting functions for converting various data types.

One example for your case could be:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('05 Dec 2000 15:15:20', 'DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS')::TIME
```

which will return `15:15:20`

Comment: THANK YOU @spasa mihajlovic

Comment: For time slots investigate using between